# Slick plugin - fixed height and auto width on div causes undefined slide width

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, slick.js

I'm using the Slick plugin and am trying to get *portrait* slides to work. This has worked great for me with landscape images and I've been setting fixed width on slick-slide divs with auto height through my css sheet.

E.g.

```
slider div {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}

slider div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However I'm now trying to do this with *portrait* images and am setting fixed height with auto width. The problem here though is that with auto width, I think the plugin doesn't know what width size to use and just assigns the div element a massive width size as there may be no support for auto.

E.g.

```
slider div {
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
}

slider div img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm still new to jQuery and am trying to figure out how width is taken from the plugin as getting .width() from the div itself (when plugin is disabled) comes out as a unit it should be.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I can do to solve this or can provide any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure, here is a js fiddle of the problem. 
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan002/swokvfrs/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set `width: auto;` for both the container and the image.

```
slider div {
    height: 250px;
}

slider div img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The above lines of code are sufficient as the slick calculates width based on the parent container's width.